# On click have a second image zoom into place and cover the previous image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have an image of a map area. I also have a second image which is a zoomed in area of the same map. I want to click a button and have the second image replace the first one, but I want some kind of an animation zoom effect to take place, also it would be nice to have a reverse animation effect for when the user clicks to see the entire map. I have no idea what approach to take on this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you guys!

The map image I use is a very stylized and minimalistic version of an actual map so I really rather just due some simple image manipulation and not use a real map api.

If there's a way to use a larger image and be able to click on a mapped area inside the image and have it zoom in and out, that I think would be the best way to handle this.

Comment: Because you are working with two images, zoom-effects will be hard. If your map is an `svg` you could scale it. You can always zoom a single large image but thats cumbersome.

Comment: Is fancyBox2 an option for you? Here's the link: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: SVG: I feel like svg is going to me more cumbersome since i have to make sure I have all the clickable areas in their own layers and then find a good way to zoom into that area. I'm not that advanced with SVGs yet.

Fancybox: I can't open a new window, I need to keep it in the same div and somehow create and animation zoom effect to replace the two images.